# Publishing to pivotal tc server has encountered... Unable to start tc server

Tags: maven-3, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I have recently installed the new STS 3.8.3 release. And immediately after I started adding dependencies to maven, my tc server stopped working and this error came up

[image]

I cant understand the problem, It came after I updated my repository indexes.
The following is the error.

> Publishing the configuration... 
>   Error copying file to
>   D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\catalina.policy:
>   D:\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)
>   D:\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy
>   (The system cannot find the path specified) Error copying file to
>   D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\catalina.properties:
>   D:\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
>   D:\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified) Error copying file to
>   D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\context.xml:
>   D:\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\context.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)
>   D:\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\context.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified) Error copying file to
>   D:/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\jmxremote.access: D:\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.access (The system cannot find the path specified)

Please help me resolve this...

(Note: I am tagging this issue under maven too, even though I am not so sure how that is related. If there is no relation please ignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `base-instance` instance of tc server is corrupted. Launching tc server backs up the config files in the `backup` folder under the `instance` folder. Looks like config files are missing and there nothing to backup.
I'd suggest removing `base-instance` folder and then starting STS again. STS should create `base-instance` automatically on the startup if it's missing.
Hope this helps

Comment: Ya, that is what I did. Now it seems to be working fine. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify whether the files it is complaining about exist?  If base-instance/conf files don't exist the default STS instance was not created correctly for some reason.   You can always delete that base-instance and recreate it or create your own instance and import it into the servers.

`> pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE/tcruntime-instance.bat create base-instance -t base --force -v 8.0.30.C.RELEASE`

Comment: i did check if the files exist. I checked for permissions too. They all seemed to be fine. I couldnt solve the issue whatsover so had to install everything from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **do not close the server** or your project will not be able to see the configuration files needed.  This happens to me when I click close unrelated projects and the 'Servers' folder closes.  To prevent this from happening I add the Servers folder to my 'project references'.  Right click project and choose properties at the bottom, then click on project references and select your Servers folder.[image: project references in eclipse or spring tool suite]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with Eclipse, but in my case conf folder was gone.
I think it could have been caused when I ran another Eclipse for another workspace, and other Eclipse messed up conf folder (no proof though).

The workaround I used was was to:

1. Re-create missing conf folder, in my case: 
   C:\Users\<UNAME>\eclipse\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server\instances\base-instance\conf
2. copy the files from your Eclipse Servers project into the conf.[image]
3. Run it

Answer (score 0):

Yes , correct , I had faced same issue.
Reason is first i had opened STS for one workspace for example Chetan_workspace with STS.

Later i openened the same workspace 'Chetan_workspace' with eclipse. that time eclipse has deleted conf folder.

i.e. conetnt of conf folder in C:\SOFTWARES\spring-tool-suite-3.9.10.RELEASE-e4.13.0-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server\instances\base-instance\conf

location .. and contents are

catalina.policy,
server.xml,
logger file etc..

solution :
just go to this location and create conf folder manually
C:\SOFTWARES\spring-tool-suite-3.9.10.RELEASE-e4.13.0-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server\instances\base-instance\conf
and add its contents mentioed above / or all contents for which it is throwing error
it worked